# Loopback.js - Upload buffer with storage component

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, loopbackjs

I'm developing an api, using Loopback.js and the `loopback-component-storage`. This component works great if one sends a file with the request, however, I'm generating some images in my server.

Each image is a buffer object. How can I upload this buffers to Amazon S3?

This is what I have so far:

```
var ss = new storageComponent.StorageService({provider: 'amazon'});
ss.client.s3Stream.upload(); // This returns a stream object
```

what can I do now with this stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Having the save issue... @danielrvt, do you solve it?